# Android SQLite selection argument

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got an SQLite database in my Android app. I want to be able to select a random row based on the YEAR column in the database. I'm already able to select a random row from the entire table like so:

```
    public String[] getTEST3RandChVerScrip() {
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query("provtable Order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
            new String[] { KEY_MAKE, KEY_MODEL, KEY_NOTE }, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast();) {
            String colStrings[] = new String[3];
            colStrings[0] = cursor.getString(0);
            colStrings[1] = cursor.getString(1);
            colStrings[2] = cursor.getString(2);
            return colStrings;
        }

    }
    return null;

}
```

But when I try and add a selection argument, the app errors out. Here's where I've added the selection argument:

```
    public String[] getTEST3RandChVerScrip() {
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query("provtable Order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
            new String[] { KEY_MAKE, KEY_MODEL, KEY_NOTE }, KEY_YEAR =  "1964",
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast();) {
            String colStrings[] = new String[3];
            colStrings[0] = cursor.getString(0);
            colStrings[1] = cursor.getString(1);
            colStrings[2] = cursor.getString(2);
            return colStrings;
        }

    }
    return null;

}
```

Is the syntax incorrect in `KEY_YEAR = "1964"`? If so any idea what it should be?

As per tyczj's answer I've modified the query to:

```
        Cursor cursor = this.db.query("provtable Order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
            new String[] { KEY_MAKE, KEY_MODEL, KEY_NOTE }, KEY_YEAR +              "=?",
            new String[] {"1964"}, null, null, null);
```

... and I'm still getting an error that says: `06-20 15:18:33.644: E/AndroidRuntime(4758): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT make, model, note FROM provtable Order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 WHERE year=?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put order by in the table name area

```
this.db.query("provtable",
            new String[] { KEY_MAKE, KEY_MODEL, KEY_NOTE }, KEY_YEAR +              "=?",
            new String[] {"1964"}, null, null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: THANK YOU Nicholas! It works just how I want it to work! I'm pretty new to SQLite, and knew what I wanted the query to do, but didn't quite get where the arguments go and how they'd be written in an Android SQLite query.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
KEY_YEAR+"=1964"
```

however better syntax wound be to put your selection as `KEY_YEAR+"=?"` and then you selectionArgs should be `new String[] {"1964"}`

also post the error